# I encountered this problem when trying to a List of tokenized words to a String in Python

Tags: python, list, nlp, typeerror, spacy

This is the code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

def listtostring(s): #Start the function to covert the content of the list into a string
    str1 = ''
    return str1.join(s)


new = ""
responese = []

reply = nlp(str(input("Input your queries:")))

for word in reply: #Removing the stop words and putting the non-stop words into the list 
    if word.is_stop == False:
        if spacy.tokens.token.Token == "":
            break
        responese.append(word)

s = responese

print(listtostring(s)) #Print the result of the string
```

When I tried running the code, it gave me this error:

`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, spacy.tokens.token.Token found.*`

I have tried using some of the sample codes from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-a-list-to-string/) but all of them did not work.

So is there anyway to untokenize the words in the list or any alternatives to solve this problem?

Comment: Did the below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your `response` is a list that you populate with `spacy.tokens.token.Token` values when you use `responese.append(word)`. You should append the `text` properties of each `Token`, **`responese.append(word.text)`**.

Also, you may shrink the code a bit. See a fixed snippet:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
def listtostring(s): #Start the function to covert the content of the list into a string
    return ' '.join(s)

responese = []
reply = nlp(str(input("Input your queries:")))
for word in reply: #Removing the stop words and putting the non-stop words into the list 
    if not word.is_stop:
        if not spacy.tokens.token.Token:
            break
        responese.append(word.text)

print(listtostring(responese)) #Print the result of the string
```

If you input `I have a dream`, the output will be `dream`.